# Public co-authorship dataset/API?

Tags: publications, authorship, collaboration

I'm applying to grad school (Fall 2018) and am searching for Professors in a specific Computer Science field that I'm interested in who work at universities relatively close to where I currently live.

I have been reading publications by professors in this field. I've been looking at authors they've co-published with and searching which universities the co-authors work at to try to find any near to where I live.

I was wondering, could I automate this process? Search through a co-authorship graph and then maybe do some web scraping to figure out which locations Professors are based. But while it seems there are many sites that allow you to search publications and see co-authorship (Google scholar, Microsoft Academic) these don't allow you to download their data set. I also found https://api.crossref.org, but this doesn't have unique identifiers for authors (either same author appears with variations in their name, or different authors are indistinguishable).

Is there a good public dataset (or query-able database) of publication co-authorship that has unique identifiers for authors?

Comment: That seems like shooting a fly with a cannon. I suggest searching for "<name of the field> <name of your state / region / local universities>" in Google; for instance, "big data Ohio" or "algebraic complexity theory Sweden".